# Extension like Picture-in-Picture (by Google) but for any part of the browser and not just videos?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Hiyah!

I'm sorry for this strange post, just need help articulating my thoughts into something practical. I really could use an extension to basically select any part of the browser window and use it as a floating window (always on top of other windows).

It'd be awesome if something like this existed and I'd love a name in that case! If not, maybe any of you know of similar open source projects that I could take a look at? I'd try to write my own extension if there's nothing like that, so basically could use any keywords to simplify my research. I've been learning full stack web dev for a few months now, so I think it's in realm of possibilities for me.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: There's no such thing in modern extension API anymore. While extensions can open a separate window and set its size but they can't make it always-on-top so its usefulness is almost zero for a typical user who keeps the browser window maximized. If you don't mind writing and installing a separate utility that sets the always-on-top state, you can use [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to start it.

Comment: Thank you for detailed reply @wOxxOm! That's really unfortunate, it seems like a simple feature to implement. I'll do more research on it and thanks for the link!